# MSSQL using Merge with nullable parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

we have a stored procedure that takes in four parameters that can be null - as an example

```
@FirstName NVARCHAR(50)
@LastName NVARCHAR(50)
@Age INT
@PhoneNumber NVARCHAR(15)
```

We have a person table with a primary key called `ID (INT, NOT NULL, IDENTITY)`

Until now we have been running a query against the database like so

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person 
where FirstName = ISNULL(@FirstName, FirstName) 
  AND LastName = ISNULL(@LastName, LastName) 
  AND AGE = ISNULL(@Age, AGE) 
  and PhoneNumber = ISNULL(@PhoneNumber, PhoneNumber)
```

I was wondering if it's possible to do the above utilising the MERGE statement of MSSQL

e.g.

```
create table #personSearch (ID INT NOT NULL)

MERGE #personSearch AS T  
    USING Person AS S
    ON 
           T.ID = S.ID
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    AND s.ID = @ID
    THEN  
    INSERT (ID)
    VALUES (s.ID);
```

That would pull across those records in the person table that do not exist in the temp table - my question is how would I do the other clauses?

Is it even worth using MERGE to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Using MERGE only to SELECT values is not worth.

Comment: in the MERGE's USING clause you can use a subquery, i.e. `MERGE personSearch AS T USING (SELECT columns FROM PERSON WHERE ... your condition here) AS S`